# non-wipe non-unlock root for Android 2.3.3

Tags: rooting, samsung-nexus-s

I have a Nexus S running Android 2.3.3.

IIRC on old android version such as this there were non-wipe non-unlock methods to obtain root anyway, however I wasn't able to find them right now.

Can this be done?

Comment: I think Gingerbreak was the main root method, which is (IIRC) what [SuperOneClick](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=803682) uses. That might be a good one to start with if you haven't tried it yet, but I'm not positive that it will work.

Comment: @eldarerathis: gingerbreak worked. Unfortunately, I lost root upgrading to 2.3.6. Still, since it worked, if you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android 2.3.3 was (on all devices I'm aware of) vulnerable to the [Gingerbreak](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/root-your-gingerbread-device-with-gingerbreak/) exploit, which used a software hole in Android to gain root permission and therefore doesn't require wiping your device. [SuperOneClick](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=803682) provides this as one of its root methods, making it a popular choice for rooting versions 2.3 to 2.3.3 of Gingerbread.